# upside down ThreeJS webgl globe

Tags: three.js, webgl-globe

I am working with the [THREE.js WebGL globe](https://github.com/dataarts/webgl-globe) and want to remove the constraint that prevents you from rotating the globe upside down: North pole being down and vice-versa.

[image: a screenshot of what i need]

Here's my current experiment: https://mgiraldo.github.io/edda-globe

I tried modifying the `onMouseMove` function (which is where I think the problem lies) but my geometry math is limited. The function:

```js
  function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (event.type!="touchmove") {
        mouse.x = - event.clientX;
        mouse.y = event.clientY;
    } else {
        mouse.x = - event.touches[0].clientX;
        mouse.y = event.touches[0].clientY;
    }

    var zoomDamp = distance/1000;

    target.x = targetOnDown.x + (mouse.x - mouseOnDown.x) * 0.005 * zoomDamp;
    target.y = targetOnDown.y + (mouse.y - mouseOnDown.y) * 0.005 * zoomDamp;

    target.y = target.y > PI_HALF ? PI_HALF : target.y;
    target.y = target.y < - PI_HALF ? - PI_HALF : target.y;
  }
```

I think the problem lies precisely on these lines:

```
    target.y = target.y > PI_HALF ? PI_HALF : target.y;
    target.y = target.y < - PI_HALF ? - PI_HALF : target.y;
```

The complete code is here: https://github.com/mgiraldo/edda-globe/blob/gh-pages/globe/globe.js#L321-338

**EDIT:** created a [Codepen for easy testing](http://codepen.io/mgiraldo/pen/gprppb?editors=001). `onMouseMove` in lines 318-334.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already found the solution? This is working for me, maybe you want to go with a value around 1 instead of Pi/2 to limit the rotation more

```
target.y = target.y > 1 ? 1 : target.y;
target.y = target.y < - 1 ? - 1 : target.y;
```

Comment: this change does not let you put the world upside down... the idea is to have south be north and vice versa... removing the lines in question lets you do this but also produces some weird "jump" in the rotation... give it a try: comment 332-333 and Run